# lateinit property listener has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add an onclick listener to a recyclerview item i however keep getting an error that states the listener has not been initialised, but it has been initialised, what am i doing wrong.

**Note: The recycler view is a nested recyclerview, and am adding the onclick to the child recyclerview**

Here is how my adapter looks like

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productModel: List<Product>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>(){

    private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductView {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false)
        return ProductView(view, productModel, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productModel.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductView, position: Int) {
        var product = productModel[position]
        //
        holder.product = listOf(product)

    }

    class ProductView(itemView: View, var product: List<Product>, listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onButtonClick(product[0])
            }
        }

    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onButtonClick(productModel: Product)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener){
        this.listener = listener
    }

}
```

And this is how am implementing it in my fragment

```
private fun addToCart(){
        productAdapter?.setOnItemClickListener(object : ProductAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onButtonClick(productModel: Product) {
                Log.v("Clicked", ""+productModel.productName)

            }

        })
    }
```

**UPDATE: I made the listener nullable i am no longer getting the error but the click doesn't log anything**

```
private var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductView {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false)
    return ProductView(view, productModel, listener)
}
```

You need to initialize `listener` before you use it. You are using it in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Make sure that you initialize `listener` before attaching your `ProductAdapter` to a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setOnItemClickListener()`, you can set listener on while constructing adapter. This will ensure that you always set click listener for adapter:

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productModel: List<Product>, listener: OnItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>(){
    // ...
}
```

Another option is making `private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener` nullable. However, it's not good practice if listener is mandatory to set:

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productModel: List<Product>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>(){

    private var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Yes i have done that, but nothing is being logged now, the eeror has gone

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is you pass `listener` to `ProductView` in constructor and use it in `init` block, which called from `onCreateViewHolder` before you set your `listener`

So to solve this issue you have two options

1- Make `listener` nullable and set it when u need, something like

```
private var listener: OnItemClickListener?
```

Then when you use it

```
class ProductView(itemView: View, var product: List<Product>, listener: OnItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val foodImg: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodImg)
        val foodName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodName)
        val foodDesc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodDesc)
        val foodPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPrice)
        private val addToCart: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart)
        private lateinit var repository: MainRepository


        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onButtonClick(product[0])
            }
        }

    }
```

2- Pass `OnItemClickListener` in adapter constructor

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productModel: List<Product>, private val listener: OnItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductView>(){
 private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener //remove this listener
.....

}
```

and you can init your adapter like this

```
val adapter = ProductAdapter(productModel, object : ProductAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onButtonClick(productModel: Product) {
                Log.v("Clicked", ""+productModel.productName)

            }

        })
```

Actually i prefer second option.

Comment: Hey thanks alot, i have implemented this and its no longer crushing, however nothing is happening, nothing is being logged

Comment: you use approach number 1, can u please add 

productAdapter?.setOnItemClickListener(object : ProductAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onButtonClick(productModel: Product) {
                Log.v("Clicked", ""+productModel.productName)

            }

        })

after initiating your adapter directly

Comment: I am using the second approach, sorry i failed to mention that

Comment: Did you removed    private lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener ?

Comment: Yes i removed it